# Routing not working for web api added to empty web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, asp.net-web-api-routing

Whilst following  [John Papa's excellent "SPA Jumpstart" course](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/single-page-apps-jumpstart) I got to the point in the tutorial at which the speakers controller is tested.  At this point my app returned a "404: Not found" error instead of loading the speakers.

In case there was something wrong with the speakersController I did a simple right-click -> add item -> add web api controller and created "valuesController" with just the standard start up methods in there.  That didn't work either, I just get:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:57219/api/values
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

In Chrome's dev tools.

I subsequently tried again from scratch with a basic empty web application project, then went to nuget and installed the Microsoft Wep Api package.  I then added "valuesController" again, still nothing. I then realised I needed to do more and added an "App_Start" folder in which I placed a file called WebApiConfig.vb.  This contained:

Imports System.Web.Http

```
Public Class WebApiConfig
    Public Shared Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="DefaultApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I added a "global.asax" file which contained:

```
Imports System.Web.SessionState
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    End Sub
End Class
```

After doing this, basic routing worked and I was able to go to that controller default page successfully.

However... despite uninstalling and reinstalling the web api package in my jumpstart project, I am still unable to get to the same URL even though all appears (to me) to be identical in the relevant files (global.asax and webApiConfig.vb).

There is another issue with "scripts/css" and other js files not being rendered by the index.vbhtml page but I don't think that's relevant to this issue as I'm trying to go straight to "...api/speakers" or "...api/values" to test therefore bypassing the index page.

I shouldn't need anything other than the web api package, right?  I have put a breakpoint in the global.asax and webapiconfig.vb pages but they're never hit - I think they're already done with by the time the debugger hooks up though. I'm totally lost for where to look now. There shouldn't be any other files capable of interfering with routing, right?

My packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Durandal" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="4.3.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="3.0.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20715.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" version="4.0.8876.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SqlServerCompact" version="4.0.8854.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="toastr" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that all packages in the packages.config of my module's after folder are included in your project?

Comment: @JohnPapa Yes John, sure have.  The list is identical. Included in original question for confirmation now.

Comment: Hmm. This is weird.  I went back to my "test" vb project where I started with a web app and added bits, folder by folder and file by file from my jumpstart project.  I am now in the position where the controllers still work and all the files are the same as far as I can tell.  Just about to check the web.config to see if that's noticeably different.  I am getting an error on the speakersController but it's a 500-server error relating to "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'." and goes on to say something about string

Comment: <ExceptionMessage>
Type 'VB$AnonymousType_2`4[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.  So it is running the controller api!  I have no idea what the difference is...

Comment: Just checked the web.config files. They are identical from one (working) version to the other (non working) version so I'm completely stumped.

Comment: The serialization error was caused by a lack of the newtonsoft json plugin.  Something must have got screwed up in my project but it works now I've recreated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dull as it is, it appears that there was some kind of corruption in the project. When I recreated it and added all my files back in from the broken project, it all worked fine.

Comment: well, glad to hear it. you had us stumped

Comment: You should mark this as answered now, so others can find the solution

Comment: Will do when it allows me to. Says 21 hours still!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're calling the WebApiConfig.Register in your global.asax?
You could also try changing the route to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
name:="DefaultApi", _
routeTemplate:="api/{controller}" _
)
```

(Just to see if this way the correct route is resolved...)

Comment: Yes, you can see it in my code posted in the original question: WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)  Also tried your other code and it made no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the tutorial is only accessibly to members, but the breakpoint not being hit makes me wonder if old code is actually being run--or Application_Start isn't firing b/c it's already run once. Have you stopped the site in the system tray between tests? The debugger should be attached.

Comment: How would I go about "Have you stopped the site in the system tray between tests" joelt?

Comment: Down in the system tray there should be an icon that looks like a page with a greenish circle and a blueish circle. If you hover over it, it says "ASP.NET Development Server". Right click and select Stop. In theory, rebuilding would do this, but it doesn't always seem to work